# datagram sockets in c. looks like parent process never binds

Tags: c, sockets, ipc, datagram

i have tried to execute the following code of two processes.
the child sends a datagram and the parent is supposed to receive it and print it
. The parent process looks like it does not bind (error: address already in use). 
any ideas?

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 9

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int pid,s,n,addrlen; 
char msg[N]; 
struct sockaddr_un addr;

addr.sun_family=AF_UNIX;        
strcpy(addr.sun_path,"test-socket");    // pathname
addrlen=sizeof(addr.sun_family)+strlen(addr.sun_path);

if (!(pid=fork())) {
    printf("child\n");
    s=socket(PF_UNIX,SOCK_DGRAM,0); 
    sleep(3); /* wait for parent to bind */

    sendto(s,"hi parent",9,0,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,addrlen);  
    printf("child sent\n");
    close(s);

    return(0);
}
printf("father\n");
s=socket(PF_UNIX,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
bind(s,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,addrlen);   // error here

n=recvfrom(s,msg,N,0,NULL,NULL);        
if(n<=0){printf("error\n");}
msg[n]='\0'; printf("%s\n",msg);
close(s);
unlink("test-socket");              

return(0);
```

}

Comment: You look to be recv'ing nine bytes into a nine byte buffer, then null terminating one byte past the buffer's end (`msg[n]`).  Can you correct that and try again?

Comment: You don't check the return values from `socket`, `bind` or `sendto`. Do this - and use `errno`/`strerror` when you log the error - and see if you're ignoring a problem.

Comment: the bind command returned error: address already in use

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you bind before fork? Waiting for a fixed amount of time and then sending data is not a good idea

Comment: tried to create socket and bind before fork..didn't work

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Mac OS X Snow Leopard) `sockaddr_un` looks like this:

```
struct  sockaddr_un {
        unsigned char   sun_len;        /* sockaddr len including null */
        sa_family_t     sun_family;     /* [XSI] AF_UNIX */
        char            sun_path[104];  /* [XSI] path name (gag) */
};
```

Assuming yours looks something similar, your calculation of `addrlen` (`sizeof(addr.sun_family)+strlen(addr.sun_path)`) is wrong, which will result in calls that use it `sendto` and `bind` using a different path than the one you think you are using – it will be truncated.

Your call to `bind` is probably creating a socket file named something like `test-socke` (note the missing `t` at the end). When your program finishes it tries to `unlink` the non-existing file `test-socket`. This means that the next time you run the program the file you are trying to `bind` to (`test-socke`) already exists, and so `bind` will fail in the way you are seeing.

To fix this you need to make sure you are using the correct length for `addrlen`. The simplest and safest way is probably to use `sizeof(addr)`:

```
addrlen = sizeoff(addr);
```

You could also use `SUN_LEN` if it is available, which might save you copying a few bytes if that concerns you:

```
addrlen = SUN_LEN(&addr);
```

If you want to calculate the correct length yourself (e.g. `SUN_LEN` isn’t availble) then try this:

```
addrlen = sizeof(addr) - sizeof(addr.sun_path) + strlen(addr.sun_path);
```

(This is adapted from the definition of `SUN_LEN` on my system.)